# Need to do a simple query

Tags: sql

I have a user table, and a Reefer column, how do i show all the users that have NULL Refer and have been Refered 1 or more other users? like:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE ReferID IS NULL AND ( 'Here is where i want to know if he refered more than 1 user' )
```

Comment: You will need to provide table schema. How do we know if user has referred someone? Is there a column specifying it?

Comment: @nadeem_MK Obviously there is: `ReferID`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a service that writes your code for you, nor is it a place for tutorials on SQL :)

Comment: @Luaan I haven't asked for the code

Comment: Since you are not asking for the code and did not provide the shcema and the DBMS you are using, we could only add some instructions what you should know to achieve this: You can use the `EXISTS` or `IN` clause to check if there is a correlating record based on a subselect. Another option is to use aggregation function and `self-join` with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses. The exact solution is depends on your business needs and the environment you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM User WHERE ReferID IS NULL AND Refered >= 1
```

Considering ReferID isnt your primary key cause a primary key can't be null
And that you have a refered column i guess it's a column where you could update each time somenes referes your stuff from this table.

Idk what's the logic behind this but as ReferID can't be null you will have a ReferKey that will be your primary key. Considering this, ReferKey and ReferID will be mostly the same and in some cases ReferID will be null. That's... different :3

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, and the first question you got in your comments already asked how to know that users "have been Refered 1 or more other users" and you gave no answer.

So let's asssume you are looking for user records identified by an id, for which another record exists where ReferID contains that id:

```
SELECT * 
FROM User 
WHERE ReferID IS NULL 
AND ID IN (SELECT ReferID FROM User);
```

If this is not already what you are looking for, it should at least help you to write your query.